# Using packages in python

Tags: python-3.x

i am learning python packages and i have the following directory structure

packdemo folder which has two folders one and two

In both the folders one and two i have a **init**.py file.
I have a variable declared in **init**.py file of one folder called mainvar

In folder named one i have useone.py file having the following code

```
    def calfact():
    print("in calfacct")
    return 10
```

In the other folder two i have another file called usingone.py with the following code

```
import packdemo.one.useone

abc=packdemo.one.useone.calfact()
print(abc)
print(packdemo.one.mainvar)
```

I am able to access both in this way. But can i access both using the 
from    import   format  as i have to write the entire package name in this case.

Comment: In addition to @Krowvin's answer, you can also choose the name that a module is assigned to with the keyword `as`. For instance, `import packdemo.one as banana` which you can then use `abc = banana.useone.calfact()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you couldn't type

```
from packdemo.one.useone import calfact
```

Then just use

```
abc = calfact()
```

Or perhaps

```
from packdemo.one import useone
```

then use:

```
abc = useone.calfact()
```

**Edit**: I'm going to update my answer. If you want to shorten your call

```
abc = packdemo.one.mainvar.init()
```

Changing this to what Bram said, you can shorten it this way:

```
import packdemo.one.mainvar as mainvar
abc = mainvar.init()
```

This goes into the directories 
packdemo > one > mainvar and accesses init.py, returning whatever the method returns

Comment: I can do this but with this import i am not able to access mainvar from the __init__ file. i need a import through which i can access both

Comment: I updated my answer with an edit, not sure if that's what your looking for. Goodluck!

Comment: mainvar is a variable declared in __init__ method in one package that we are trying to print. see the second print statement in the question asked

Comment: Interesting, so you have an init method? (Not \_\_init\_\_ right?) and that is **def**ined within init.py? So something like import packdemo.one.mainvar.init as init and you would call abc = init.init()

Well, i'm not trying to confuse things, so we can see if someone else answers. But you might post a link to your structure on a git repo if you don't get any replies.

Comment: Due apologies. mainvar is a variable declared in the  \_\_init\_\_.py file in the folder one. I am trying to access both the variable in the \_\_init\_\_.py file as well as the method in the useone.py file with the import. Due apologies i wrote method for it.